# How to read variable number of files and then combine the data frames in R?

Tags: r

I would like to design a function. Say I have files file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, ..., file100.csv. I only want to read some of them every time I call the function by specifying an integer vector id, e.g., id = 1:10, then I will read file1.csv,...,file10.csv.

After reading those csv files, I would like to row combine them into a single variable. All csv files have the same column structure.

My code is below:

```
  namelist <- list.files() 
  for (i in id) { 
    assign(paste0( "file", i ), read.csv(namelist[i], header=T))
  }
```

As you can see, after I read in all the data matrix, I stuck at combining them since they all have different variable names.

Comment: My id is a vector...let me update the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read in each file as an element of a list. Then you can combine them as follows:

```
namelist <- list.files()
df <- vector("list", length = length(id))
for (i in id) {
    df[[i]] <- read.csv(namelist[i], header = TRUE)
}
df <- do.call("rbind", df)
```

Or more concisely:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(), read.csv))
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to mine, +1

Comment: Thanks. But OP wanted a single variable not a data.frame so yours answers more correctly I think!

Comment: Why is this solution more elegant?

Comment: In general it's better (faster and more memory efficient) to specify the final length of an object in advance than to let it grow in a loop. Check out Circle 2 of The R Inferno for more on this.

Answer (score 3):

I do this, which is more R like without the for loop:

```
## assuming you have a folder full of .csv's to merge
filenames <- list.files()

all_files <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do then this is all you need:

```
namelist <- list.files() 
singlevar = c()
for (i in id) { 
  singlevar = rbind(singlevar, read.csv(namelist[i], header=T))
}
```

Since in the end you want one single object to contain all the partial information from the single files, `rbind` as you go.

Comment: I think you mean: singlevar <-  rbind(singlevar, read.csv(namelist[i], header=T)). This works!

Comment: @dannycrane yes, was already editing. the solution by choff is more elegant in my eyes, in the end they work both